# Execute Python subprocess.run which goes on to call an external MPIRUN command

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, subprocess, mpi

I'm facing a slight problem with a *hidden* MPIRUN call inside a program called ORCA during an external call from python using subprocess.run(). I would appreciate some assistance troubleshooting.

I am using Python 3.8.3 within Jupyter Notebook 6.0.3 on Windows 10. My workflow performs an external call from python to the ORCA orca.exe program using:

```
fileHandler = open(outputFileStr, "w")
result = subprocess.run([orcaLocationStr, inputFileStr], cwd=cwdStr, shell=True, stdout=fileHandler)
```

**NOTE**: I've tried tweaking the `subprocess.run()` parameters, what you see is just one iteration of many. I think the fundamental issue I face is the one I describe below.

The external call essential recreates the Windows command terminal call:

```
c:\ORCA\orca my_inputfile.inp
```

(Note: I would have added `> output.out` if I was executing ORCA from the terminal. However, via python, I've redirected the output to a file).

The variable `orcaLocationStr` contains `c:\ORCA\orca`. The absolute path to orca.exe is required (even if it's in your PATH env variable) to use its multiprocessing capabilities.

The variable `inputFileStr` points to a file that contains the parameters required by ORCA. One of those parameters is the number of processes e.g., `nproc 16`.

All was going well until ORCA crashed. orca.exe turns out to be a wrapper to several other .exe files within the ORCA homedirectory. The `nproc` parameters I mentioned earlier is used so the orca.exe wrapper can execute `n` child processes using `mpirun`. That is when executing orca.exe within Python crashes and returns a non-zero value.  I know this having performed some basic checks:

**N processes** specified in the ORCA parameter file. **Calls** MPIRUN.

1. The command will execute from the Windows command line using `N` processes.
2. The command fails when executing from Python using subprocess.run().

**1 process** specified in the ORCA parameter file. Does **not** call MPIRUN.

1. The command will execute from Windows command line using 1 process.
2. The command will execute from Python using subprocess.run().

I think it's important to be clear, it is not Python executing MPIRUN. It is an external binary called by Python that executes MPIRUN.

How can I make a Python process ready to accept multiple child processes via an external-embedded MPIRUN call?

**EDIT #1** I am expecting my software to (a) perform all the preprocessing steps such as performing IO tasks etc., then (b) I want to use subprocess.run() 1600 times - as I have 1600 input files to execute. I am wondering if all else fails, whether to move just this part across to something like Bash and execute independent of Python.

Comment: some MPI implementations do not support a task directly spawning an other process.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I understand this is a bit of an open question, but do you think a Bash alternative would work i.e., have python do 95% of the work (preparing files etc), then switch over to running Bash to execute ORCA? I've added a couple of more details under EDIT.